# Relate WhoId on a task Record with a new custom object

Tags: page-layout, tasks

WhoId and WhatId are both "polymorphic" fields, meaning they can be related to different objects, defined by the ID itself.
We can relate WhatId on a Task record to a different custom object by checking "Allow Activities" checkbox on the custom object settings page. But what about WhoId?

Currently I see that WhoId is associated with either contacts or leads. How can we associate WhoId with another custom object? And is this really possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [can't be done](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm?q=task)

`WhoId` can only be `Lead`, `Contact`

> The WhoId represents a human such as a lead or a contact. WhoIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhoId is equivalent to a contact’s ID or a lead’s ID. The label is Name ID.
>
> This is a polymorphic relationship field.
>
> Relationship Name
>
> Who
>
> Relationship Type
>
> Lookup
>
> Refers To
>
> Contact, Lead

`WhatId` can be any custom object plus a bunch of standard objects like `Opportunity`